# Angular 5 not change route with router.navigate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, rxjs

I've a chrome extension (or browser plugin) which I using Angular 5 for popup. Some considerations before the problem, I've a login screen which redirect for main component (flight component), so `router.navigation` in this case works as expected.

At navigation bar in extension, I've a listener for messages from a **background script**, which listen user actions, when he change view and notify my extensio. e.g. change from flight view to hotel view.

When this action occur, I need change flight component to hotel component. To do this I've a service which listen messages emitted from **background script**, various types messages are emitted, so I filter to get only correct message. Follow the code which I capture the `value.type`.

In my `navbar` I've the subscription to message.

```
this.message
    .filter(value => value.hasOwnProperty('type'))
    .subscribe((value) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/' + value.type]);
    });
```

At this point all occur was expect even navigate are called, but not change to hotel component when value is type hotel or car, stay "locked" in flight component.

More info about application:

- Navigate from login to flight occur as expected
- I'm using canActivate for protected routes like flight, hotel and car
- Flight, hotel and car aren't child route.

Comment: I do not really get it. It is hard to image the structure. Could you please share snippets of your code in some more comprehensive app context? Also, would exactly do you mean by 'chrome extension' that sound like browser plugin to me, but I cannot place it into the context of what you wrote.

Comment: Is browser plugin which communicate with another scripts. A background script and popup which is wrote in Angular 5.

Comment: I understood your point well. And I have the same problem in my angular application 5 here! When I use `router.navigate(['/mypage'])` and it does not work, but if I use `router.navigateByUrl('/mypage')` it works normally